# How to draw a circle in HTML5 Canvas using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How to draw a simple circle in HTML5 Canvas using minimum JavaScript code?

Comment: @Kinrany I agree.  There's no way this is too broad.  The question arises from there not being a simple "drawCircle" command in the API.  Instead we must do a peculiar set of steps involving `beginPath`, `arc`, `fill`, etc. And we must understand a circle is a special case of an arc, and what start and end angles are appropriate or optimal.  It's also not clear whether it's necessary to call `closePath` That's all we're looking for with this question.  This question shouldn't be closed for being too broad.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Here is how to draw a circle using JavaScript in HTML5:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const centerX = canvas.width / 2;
const centerY = canvas.height / 2;
const radius = 70;

context.beginPath();
context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.fillStyle = 'green';
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
context.stroke();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: If you want to draw multiple circles in a for-loop for example, only filling once after the loop, make sure to use `context.moveTo(x, y)` before the call to arc().

Comment: How to update this graph if we want to clear old circle value to new value.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Answer (score 16):

I took the answers above and turned them into a useful function:

```
function drawCircle(ctx, x, y, radius, fill, stroke, strokeWidth) {
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false)
  if (fill) {
    ctx.fillStyle = fill
    ctx.fill()
  }
  if (stroke) {
    ctx.lineWidth = strokeWidth
    ctx.strokeStyle = stroke
    ctx.stroke()
  }
}
```

Then, use it like so to draw a black circle with a red stroke (width 2) at coordinates 50,50, with radius 25:

```
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
drawCircle(ctx, 50, 50, 25, 'black', 'red', 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

Creating shapes is easier using new Canvas [Path2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D), which uses the same canvas drawing API, and allow separation of the declaration from drawing itself, and reuse of complex geometry:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 70;

let circle = new Path2D();  // <<< Declaration
circle.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

context.fillStyle = 'blue';
context.fill(circle); //   <<< pass circle to context

context.lineWidth = 10;
context.strokeStyle = '#000066';
context.stroke(circle);  // <<< pass circle here too
```

```css
body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you need to get the canvas context:-

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Now let us define the position and radius:-

```
const X = canvas.width / 2;
const Y = canvas.height / 2;
const radius = 45;
```

Now let us set the color and line width:-

```
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
```

Now, to draw the circle, we have to use the arc method and set the angle to 2 X π

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(X, Y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 2):

Base on Sam's answer, I combined all the parameters into one object so that it is more readable when using the function.

```
function drawCircle(obj) {
obj.ctx.beginPath();
obj.ctx.arc(obj.x, obj.y, obj.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
if (obj.fill) {
    obj.ctx.fillStyle = obj.fill;
    obj.ctx.fill();
}
if (obj.stroke) {
    obj.ctx.lineWidth = obj.strokeWidth;
    obj.ctx.strokeStyle = obj.stroke;
    obj.ctx.stroke();
}
}
```

To use:

```
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');    
drawCircle({
            ctx: ctx,
            x: 100,
            y: 100,
            radius: 20,
            fill: "green",
        });
```