# How to draw a SVG on Canvas using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, canvas

How Can I draw this svg on a Canvas using Javascript (Without using Dom) ?

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
   Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

Note: Answers in post [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768565/drawing-an-svg-file-on-a-html5-canvas) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768565/drawing-an-svg-file-on-a-html5-canvas?rq=1) Only give a solution when you have an external SVG. My requirement is to draw multiple svgs on Canvas (or anything else) with variable x,y, radius and color

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25095549/8620333 ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif this is not an SVG I want to draw SVG so that On zoom it does not pixelate. this will pixelate on zoom

Comment: from what I know this not the pupose of canvas. SVG is made for scalable vector and canvas is made for bitmap and pixel by pixel rendring. (https://www.educba.com/svg-vs-canvas/). Even if you draw the content of an SVG inside a canvas you will still have issue with zomming

Comment: from the link above : *SVG does not depend on the resolution, means it is resolution independent. If we enlarge the image, it will not lose its shape. Canvas is resolution dependent. If the image is enlarged, it will start reflecting the pixels of the image.*

Comment: @TemaniAfif is there an alternative for that ? how can I make a scalable canvas like thing using javascript I need to pass x,y dynamically to it

Comment: You clearly don't need canvas. What you need is SVG. I guess you have to re-think your choices because you are trying to do things with the wrong tool.

Comment: Why i was using canvas was because you just pass x y and stroke multiple shapes is the same possible on svg too using javascript ?

Comment: Yes possible, simply take the time to read more about SVG because you can also place element using coordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use image to draw (so snippet not works - but when you edit it - it works)

```js
let xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(circSvg);   // get svg data
let svg64 = btoa(xml);                         // make it base64
let b64Start = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,';
let image64 = b64Start + svg64;                // prepend a "header"

circImg.src = image64;                         // image source
circImg.onload = x=> {
  can.getContext('2d').drawImage(circImg, 0, 0); // draw
}
```

```html
svg<br>
<svg id="circSvg" width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
   Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg> 

<br>canvas<br> <canvas id="can"></canvas>

<img id="circImg" style="display:none">
```

Comment: I see an empty canvas (using Chrome)

Comment: try now (i use setTimeout to wait some time...)

Comment: still nothing ..

Comment: I add jsfiddle - in SO snippets doesnt works... strange

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski you've forgotten to wait for the image onload event. it's random whether it works or not

Comment: Yes it works randomly and stops working randomly weird

Comment: @RobertLongson yes - you are right - fixed

Comment: @dota2pro it convert binary string to ascii string - more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is it possible to draw SVG without using a HTML Dom element, I want to draw SVGs in for loop and having them already in DOM is not possible for me `let xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(circSvg);`

Comment: you can create xml-s for each svg (you can grab svg from DOM by proper querySelector) and draw them on single canvas

Comment: in above case if there is no svg in HTML what do replace `circSvg` with in Javascript ? So without svg in DOM it isnt possible ?

Comment: you can use `let svgArr = [...document.querySelector('svg')]` to grab array of svg-s and iterate over it - if you don't have svg in dom - then this array will be empty - so any loop iteration will be executed and your canvas will be empty

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski can u please explain how to get svg data from canva. i have canva in which i have loaded svg its displaying svg but am unable to get svg to do operations on it  , i tried 
`var groupElement = document.querySelector('#canvas');var bboxGroup = groupElement.getBBox();console.log(bboxGroup);`

Comment: @user889030 as far I know, there is no build function to convert canvas raster data to svg vector graphic. However maybe you find some library which allows to do that