# how to get a circle by setting equal width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery

need to set `height` of an element equal to its `width`

i.e. - to get a perfect circle

here is the try and console shows equal values but the resulting `height` is **obviously** much higher then the `width`

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
let box = $('#box');
let w = box.width();
console.log(w);
box.height(w);
let h = box.height();
console.log(h);
});
```

```css
.box{background:orange; width:30%; border-radius:50%; overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<br><br>
<div class='box' id='box'>
lorem ipsum<br>
lorem ipsum<br>
lorem ipsum<br>
lorem ipsum<br>
lorem ipsum<br>
</div>
<br><br>
```

Comment: *obviously*: I don't get it. Looks like a perfect circle to me. What device are you working with? Did you set the resolution of your display to one that corresponds to its aspect-ratio? If a pixel is not a square, then obviously, nothing will look as it should...

Comment: @trincot, I'm on a desktop PC, newest Chrome and can see a perfect circle on another pages

Comment: Does [this canvas circle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25095549/5459839) look fine to you?

Comment: @trincot seems a slightly vertical elipsed to me

Comment: Then your screen is not using the optimal resolution. I think you should change it.

Comment: And another remark: in your code the width of the `div` will dynamically follow the viewport's width, while the click handler will set the height to whatever the width was at the moment of the click. If for some reason there is a re-flow of the DOM (for instance when you zoom or resize the window), the width will follow that change dynamicly, but the height stays fixed.

Comment: @trincot - I'm on win 7. display resolution is 1366 x 768 (recommended). Any other option deforms the pictures. Where can I check if pixels are square or not?

Comment: Draw a square in a canvas element (of 600x600 pixels), measure the width and height with a physical measure tool. They should be the same. Or measure [this square](http://www.kidsmathgamesonline.com/images/pictures/shapes/square.jpg). It has the same height/width in pixels, so it should have equal physical measures.

Comment: @trincot, on `kidsmath...` the width is also slightly smaller then the height, but can't find where and what to set to see it properly. My screen resolution is 1366 x 768 (recommended) and any other option deforms the screen

Comment: Then there is no solution than to buy a better monitor.... Check on another device like tablet, phone, tv, ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the of `width` and `height` and assign to ot the minimum of both.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
    let box = $('#box');
    let l = Math.min(box.width(), box.height());
    box.height(l);
    box.width(l);
});
```

```css
.box{background:orange; width:30%; border-radius:50%; overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<br><br>
<div class='box' id='box'>
lorem ipsum<br>
lorem ipsum<br>
lorem ipsum<br>
lorem ipsum<br>
lorem ipsum<br>
</div>
<br><br>
```

Comment: your result is not a circle again, but an elipse

Comment: i see a circle.