# Draw function with no display how to fix?

Tags: javascript, canvas, draw

I have a simple JavaScript script that is supposed to draw a circle inside a canvas. However, when I run the html I see no circle on the page at all. I can't see any problems with my code.

I tried to change the way I select the canvas from querySelector to getElementById but it still had no effect. I even log the instance of Player to show it exists.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("game-canvas")
//character 

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

canvas.width = innerWidth canvas.height = innerHeight

class Player { 
    constructor(x, y, radius, color) {
        this.x = x 
        this.y = y 
        this.radius = radius  
        this.color = color
}
draw() {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, this.color, 0, Math.PI * 2)
    ctx.fill()
}
const player = new Player(100, 100, 100, 'blue') 
player.draw()
console.log(player)
```

```css
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="game-canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Draw isn’t right

Comment: The syntax error in your code won't be helping. (It's possible you introduced that while transcribing your code to SO, but please make use of the live demo feature and *test* your [mcve]s!). On a related note, please include the minimal HTML to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I converted your code back into a live demo. You still have the same trivial syntax error where you forgot a `;` or new line. And the other syntax error where you forgot a `}`.

Comment: Put your code in a code editor and ask it to format it, then read the error log, because right now you code simply has basic syntax errors. Which you'll also see if you look at your dev tools console. If you're not using a code editor, time to start using one, or you're not using one that doesn't have JS-specific tools like formatting and linting built in, time to install JS-specific helpers that will call out these problems for you before you ever even try to run your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095548/how-to-draw-a-circle-in-html5-canvas-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should fix like this

```
draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much. I am new to Sackoverflow but I couldn't find a solution everywhere I looked!

Comment: Nice to see good working. Good luck.